# Electrolytic silver deposition

Tags: electrochemistry

> A current is applied to two electrolytic cells in a series. In the first, silver is deposited; in the second, a zinc electrode is consumed. How much $\ce{Ag}$ is plated out if $\pu{7.5 g}$ of $\ce{Zn}$ dissolves?

What I ended up doing was

$$\frac{\pu{7.5 g}~\ce{Zn}}{\pu{65.382 g mol}~\ce{Zn}} \times \frac{\pu{2 mol}~\ce{Ag}}{\pu{1 mol}~\ce{Zn}} \times \pu{107 g mol-1}~\ce{Ag}$$

but I'm not even sure I'm doing this right.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to start with writing down the processes occurring during the electrolysis:

\begin{align}
&\text{Cathode (–):} &\ce{2 Ag+ + 2 e- &-> Ag^0} \\
&\text{Anode (+):} &\ce{Zn^0 &-> Zn^2+ + 2e} \\
\hline
&\text{Net} &\ce{2 Ag+ +Zn^0 &-> 2 Ag^0 + Zn^2+}
\end{align}

Applying the unified equation for [Faraday's laws of electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_laws_of_electrolysis):

$$m = \frac{QM}{zF}$$

for each cell, and taking into account that in series circuits current is the same for every element ($I = \text{const}$):

$$\frac{Q}{F} = \frac{z_i m_i}{M_i} = \text{const}$$

$$\frac{z(\ce{Ag}) \cdot m(\ce{Ag})}{M(\ce{Ag})} = \frac{z(\ce{Zn}) \cdot m(\ce{Zn})}{M(\ce{Zn})}$$

The valency numbers of ions are 1 and 2 for silver and zinc, correspondingly. The last thing to do is to express and calculate $m(\ce{Ag})$.

> $$m(\ce{Ag}) = \frac{z(\ce{Zn}) \cdot M(\ce{Ag})}{z(\ce{Ag}) \cdot M(\ce{Zn})} \cdot m(\ce{Zn}) = \frac{2 \cdot \pu{107.87 g mol-1}}{1 \cdot \pu{65.38 g mol-1}} \cdot \pu{7.5 g} = \pu{24.7 g}$$